# Cofinite topology on an infinite set $X$ is connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Here is my proof of that the cofinite topology on an infinite set $X$ is connected.

$X$ is connected $\iff$ There are no non-empty disjoint open subsets $U, V \subseteq X$ such that $U \cup V = X$.

Let $U, V \in X$ be non-empty disjoint open subsets of $X$ such that $U \cup V = X$.

As $U \cup V = X$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$,

$\implies U^c = V$ and $V^c = U$.

$\implies U$ and $V$ are finite sets.

$\implies U \cup V$ is finite.

But $U \cup V = X$ which is infinite so we have a contradiction. Hence there are no non-empty disjoint open subsets $U, V \subseteq X$ such that $U \cup V = X$. So $X$ is connected.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: {deleted}...cheers.

Comment: That is "if and only if". It's often the definition of connectedness.

Comment: Who bunped this question...?

Answer (score 2):

*(To remove this from the unanswered list)*

Your proof is correct.

There are not even disjoint non-empty open sets in this space.